# Unity3D & ObjC : Call API in .cs file from .m/.mm file

Tags: c#, objective-c, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I don’t know how to call function in .cs file from .m file.

Example:

```
// In file MotoState.cs
public class MotoState : MonoBehaviour {

    public static void setMotors()
    {
        // do something here
    }

    public static void getMotors()
    {
        // call function in AppDelegate from here
    }

}

// In .m file
@interface UnityAppController : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>
{
}
+(void)callSetMotors;
+(void)callThisFromGetMotors;
```

1. How to call setMotors() function in .cs file from callSetMotors() function in .m file ?
2. How to call callThisFromGetMotors() function in .m file from getMotors() in .cs file ?

Here no object reference required. All are static function.

Comment: Are this file is in the same namespace?

Comment: Atleast is it possible to add global c function in c# file and .mm file and communicate? I tried but no success.